# Approximation of alternating series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = 0.55 - (0.55)^3/3! + (0.55)^5/5! - (0.55)^7/7! + ...$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = 0.55 - (0.55)^3/3! + (0.55)^5/5! - (0.55)^7/7! + ...$

I am asked to find the no. of terms needed to approximate the partial sum to be within  0.0000001 from the convergent value of that series. Hence, I tried find the remainder, $R_n = S-S_n$ by the improper integral

$\int_{n}^{\infty} \frac{ (-1)^n(0.55)^{2n-1}} {(2n-1)!} dn $

However, I don't know how to integrate this improper integral so is there other method to solve this problem?

Comment: This is an "alternating" series, not an "alternative" series.

Comment: You are trying to use integral test-based estimation on an alternating series. The integral test is only valid when $a_n=f(n)$ with $f$ a positive continuous decreasing function. $(-1)^n$ is not continuous, so you have no hope of integrating what you have written. Instead, you should look into alternating series test-based estimation, which is actually much simpler to execute.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For an [alternating series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series) the error is less than the first neglected term, so just keep calculating until the terms get smaller than $10^{-7}$

Comment: I always wonder why one would generally choose to estimate a series like this with a partial sum rather than averaging two consecutive partial sums. The error in $\frac{S_N+S_{N+1}}{2}$ is bounded by $\frac{1}{2}b_{N+1}$ and depending on the series, that could reduce the number of terms that are used by quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks for telling me using this method. Is it possible to evaluate the no. of terms by solving the inequality $R_n < a_{n+1}$ ?

Comment: @alex.jordan: You are absolutely right that averaging will cut the maximum error by a factor of $2$. However, in the case of a rapidly converging alternating series like this one, if we are going to compute the "next term" for the purpose of averaging, one might as well add **all** of it instead of averaging. The error will be quite a bit smaller.

Comment: @KaKinLau:  You can do it approximately.  You want $10^{-7} \lt \frac {0.55^n}{n!}$ then take the logs to get $-7 \log 10 \lt n \log 0.55 + n \log n -n$ (where I used Stirling's approximation and ignored the $\sqrt {2 \pi n}$ term.  You can't do it algebraically, but a little root finding will get you there.  For this problem, $n$ is not very large and you can just try them.  I find $n=9$ works with room to spare, so only five terms.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is an alternating series, the "alternating series estimation theorem" states that the "remainder" $R_n = | s - s_n | $ is no larger than the absolute value of the next term in the series $| a_{n+1} |$.  The desired precision ($10^{-7}$ , in your case) can be set as greater than this term.

The way your summation is written, the general term is

$$ \ a_n = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}  \cdot x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!} \ ,$$

so the inequality based on the "next term" will be

$$| \frac{(-1)^{(n+1)-1} \cdot x^{2(n+1)-1}}{(2[n+1]-1)!} | \ \le 10^{-7}  \ \Rightarrow \  \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}  \ \le 10^{-7} \ .$$

This is not too convenient to think about, so we can take reciprocals in the inequality (remembering, of course, to reverse the sign!):

$$ \ \Rightarrow \  \frac{(2n+1)!}{x^{2n+1}}  \ \ge \ 10^7 \ .$$

We are evaluating the series at $x = 0.55$, but it will not introduce any significant disturbance in the result to solve this for $ \ x = 0.5 \ $:

$$ \frac{(2n+1)!}{(\frac{1}{2})^{2n+1}} \ = \ 2^{2n+1}  \cdot  (2n+1)!\ \ge \ 10^7 \ .$$

Now, an inequality with a factorial in it is not going to be something we can solve "algebraically", but we can get an estimate for  $ \ n \ $ pretty quickly if we know some factorial values.  Since $ \ 2n + 1 \ $ is odd, we note that $ \ 9! \approx 360,000 \ $ and $ \ 11! \approx 40,000,000 \ $ , so starting from $ \ n = 4 \ $ would be a good first attempt:

$$2^{2 \cdot 4 \ + \ 1}  \cdot  (2 \cdot 4 \ + \ 1)! \ = \ 2^9 \cdot 9! \ \approx \ 500 \cdot 360,000 \ \approx \ 1.8·10^8 \ \ge \ 10^7  \ , $$

indicating that $ \ n = 4 \ $ certainly does the job.  The only remaining question is whether we could cut the finite series back by one term more.  Setting $ \ n = 3 \ $ yields

$$2^{2 \cdot 3 \ + \ 1}  \cdot  (2 \cdot 3 \ + \ 1)! \ = \ 2^7 \cdot 7! \ \approx \ 130 \cdot 5000 \ \approx \ 660,000 \ \le \ 10^7  \ , $$

so we cannot spare the $ \ n = 4 \ $ term.  Your summation has an initial index of $ n = 1 $ , but the exponent in the general term is $ \ 2n - 1 \ $ , so we have need of **five** terms to reach the desired level of precision.  (Indeed, we find that the fifth term produces $ \ + \frac{0.55^9}{9!} \ \approx \ 1.27·10^{-8} \ $ , so we have attained entirely adequate precision; the fourth term is only $ \ - \frac{0.55^7}{7!} \ \approx \ -3.0·10^{-6} \ $, which does not affect the seventh decimal place.)

[**Warning to students:** a "popular" (with exam-writers -- not necessarily exam-*takers*) multiple-choice question is to ask how many terms are needed for a given level of precision for a series.  Always check what the **initial** index of the series is and which terms in the series have **non-zero** coefficients.  It may be that a series has all the terms up to $ \ n = 8 \ $, but the count begins at $ \ n = 0 \ $, so in fact *nine* terms are required.  In the problem here, the series runs to the *ninth*-power term, and the initial index is $ \ n = 1 \ $, but only *five* terms are used.  So it is important to have an awareness of the specificiations for the series being evaluated.]

Comment: Sorry about the various passes of revisions on this one: the expression for the general term is a little strange here, since it is more typical to use $ \ n = 0 \ $ as the initial index and to write the general term for sine as $ \ \frac{(-1)^n \ \cdot \ x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \ $.  The main point I wanted to make is that there is a reasonable way of getting a very good first "guess" for $ \ n \ $.

Answer (score 3):

Your general sum,
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
$$
is the power series of a trigonometric function. Note that I've corrected the limits a little bit so that the correct terms come out negative. Do you know what that function is? Given that, can you evaluate the sum?

Comment: It should be the sin function but I still don't know how to calculate it

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

$\sin x=x-\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+\dfrac{x^5}{5!}-\dfrac{x^7}{7!}+ \dots$

Your expression is simply $\sin (0.55)$.